# How to use a C++ dll in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML App within C++ Runtime Component

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, dll, windows-phone-8.1

I want to use a C++ dll (compiled for arm, x86) within my C# windows phone 8.1 XAML visual studio project.

I created a C++ runtime component to interact with my C++ code. This code needs a precompiled dll. I added my lib file to my project settings. The compilation is running fine.
If I start my app with the windows phone 8.1 emulator I get:

```
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

My Visual Studio Project Structure:

- c#

  - Windows Phone Project
  - Windows Project
  - Shared XAML
- Managed C++

  - RuntimeComponent Windows Phone
  - RuntimeComponent Windows
  - Shared C++ Code (dll used here)

[image]

Things I have tried:

- I dragged and dropped the dll into my C++ project and changed properties  of content to true.
- I dragged and dropped the dll into my C# project and enabled the option to copy the dll to the output directory

So, how can I use a .lib/.dll library within a C++ Runtime Component Project?

**Some more details:**

- I want to use Angle (which allows OpenGL Code to be executed as DirectX on Windows/Windows Phone with the Microsoft fork: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/angle/tree/future-dev)
- There are templates provided for Windows Phone 8.1 for pure C++ based on libEGL.lib/dll and libGLES.lib/dll (manually compiled for arm, win32)
- But I want to use a C# project with C++ Runntime Component to be able to use third party libs like the admob ad framework for Windows Phone
- I found out that cocos2d is using Angle but I have not figured out how they did it (https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/v3/templates/cpp-template-default/proj.wp8-xaml)

Comment: Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) what you are trying to do?

Comment: No I do not want to call C++ Code directly within C# code. The C# code calls a runtime component method (managed c++) and within this managed c++ code I want to use a C++ dll.

Comment: To link with the library, you might have to add the .lib file to the project configuration under Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies.

Comment: I have already added the lib file there

Comment: did you also right click on dll > include in project?

Comment: Yes (within the FrameworkRuntimeComponent.WindowsPhone project) but it's not copied to the out dir. It's also not working if I copy it manually

Comment: Are you really using Managed C++, or are you just creating a CX component? They are not the same thing, and Managed C++ is not supported on Windows Phone. Also, are you trying to include any binaries (lib, dll, etc.) that are not being re-built from source for Phone?

Comment: @PeterTorr has a valid question. Also, you should set the Copy to Output Directory property of dll file to Copy Always OR you can add the the dll as a `link`  (Add > Existing Item > Add as Link) and set Copy to Output Directory property of dll file to Copy Always.

Comment: First things first: you can not use OpenGL ES on WP8.1 (or any WP). You need to use Direct3D

Comment: I added some more details to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

You have to import the dll into the C#-project. It's important that the dll is in the root the C#-project and that: `copy to output directory` is **not** activated.

Comment: Would you be able to share some more details or perhaps post your boilerplate on GitHub? I am trying to get this working but am getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error when trying to call anything from the RT Component.

Comment: SImply drag and drop your dll's into your C# project (based on the screenshot: into App3.WindowsPhone) But not in any folder. That is all.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did but then I got that other error. I then just started from scratch and left as much code as possible in the C++, just forwarding the necessary events and a reference to the swapchainpanel from C# to C++ and now it is working.

Comment: I have added the third party c libraries those are related to ffmpeg such as avcodec-57.dll, avutil.dll and many others. I have followed all the steps. But I still get the following error.

"An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in App1.WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code"

Does anybody have idea to crack it?