# How to use third party dll in windows phone 8.1 application with windows runtime component?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have created the windows phone 8.1 application in which I want to use third party dll file. That's why I have created windows runtime component for the windows phone project. I have given reference of the runtime component to the windows phone 8.1 application project.

In windows runtime component, I have set the additional Include directory path. Moreover, I have also set the Linker -> Input ->additional dependencies as lib file listing. I have drag drop all dll files in my c# windows phone application main project folder and set build action as content and copy output directory as copy always.

However, I got the following error.

An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in App1.WindowsPhone.exe but was not handled in user code

I have checkout the following question. But did not resolve it.
[How to use a C++ dll in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML App within C++ Runtime Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713435/how-to-use-a-c-dll-in-windows-phone-8-1-xaml-app-within-c-runtime-component)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. All the dependencies has been set properly. There was an issue in the dll file which architecture does not match with  the current platform.

After created the build for proper architecture, it works.